Javascript to find time between two dates
I've come up empth on searches. Looking for javascript to find the number of year, months, and days from a known date to whateve the current year, month, and day is. For examle, how many years, months, and days since, say December 1, 2019 to whatever the current year, month, and day it is when the page is viewed. Hope that makes sense.
I've found script to calculate the time from one known date to another known date but I want the second known date to be the current date when viewed.

Next look up how to get the current date and make that the second known date.

This problem is under-specified. What is the expected result for 2024-02-28 and 2025-03-01? One year and two days or one year and one day? In which year do you count the number of days, in the leap year or in the regular year? What are the expected results for 2024-02-29 and 2025-02-28 resp. 2024-02-28 and 2025-02-28`?
